# I tried to create a topic with anible but I got an error kafka-run-class.sh: line 309: exec: java: not found

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create topic using ansible-playbook

```
---
- name: Create topics
  hosts: all
  vars:
    kafka_topics: /home/kafka/kafka_2.11-2.4.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh 
    kafka_server: 172.16.1.20
    kafka_port: 9092
    kafka: "{{ kafka_server }}:{ { kafka_port }}"
    zookeeper_server: 172.16.1.20
    zookeeper_port: 2181
    zookeeper: "{{ zookeeper_server }}:{ { zookeeper_port }}"
    replication_factor: 2
    partitions: 10

  tasks:

    - name: Load CERT topics to create
      include_vars:
        file: ../vars/create_topics.yml

    - name: Create Topics
      command:
        argv: 
          - "{{ kafka_topics }}"
          - --create
          - --zookeeper
          - "{{ zookeeper }}"
          - --replication-factor 
          - "{{ replication_factor }}"
          - --partitions 
          - "{{ partitions }}"
          - --topic
          - "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ topics }}"
```

I got an error "kafka-run-class.sh: line 309: exec: java: not found."

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: `java: not found` error suggests that Java is either not installed or not available in `PATH`.

Comment: But i checked it installed

Comment: Does the command `kafka-topics.sh` work when directly run on a machine?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether Java is installed and the environment variables are set [echo $JAVA_HOME should return Java home directory path and echo $PATH should return the Java binary path]. If not install Java and set up the environment variables.
2. Check whether the user has permission to Java, if not provide permission.
3. Add a debugging code in your playbook and check the output

> - name: Echo Java HOME
>   command: echo $JAVA_HOME
>   register: out
> - name: Debug JAVA_HOME
>   debug: var=out.stdout_lines